# Why does VB.NET throw OverflowException by default?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, exception, f#

From MSDN:

> For the arithmetic, casting, or conversion operation to throw an OverflowException, the operation must occur in a checked context. By default, arithmetic operations and overflows in Visual Basic are checked; in C#, they are not. If the operation occurs in an unchecked context, the result is truncated by discarding any high-order bits that do not fit into the destination type.

From what I know, by default, C# and F# doesn't check for arithmetic overflow/underflow because of performance. But why does VB.NET check them as default?

Comment: "because the language designers thought that should be the default" - that's pretty much the start and end of it; they simply made different decisions / compromises between the competing interests of unexpected results vs performance

Comment: Its a setting from the `Default Template`... which can be modified if you would like (Advanced Build Settings), but what is the point. If you don't want it un check it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OverflowException only in VB.net, not in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311162/overflowexception-only-in-vb-net-not-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Neolisk It's related, but it doesn't answer my question *by default?*.

Comment: Because VB versions before VB.NET already did that by default.   Always nice when you can start from scratch and don't have to be compatible with anything.  That C# projects don't have this option turned on in the Debug configuration is a pretty big mistake imo.  But easily corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, one should be diligent in their design so unintended overflow doesn't occur, like some lower level languages demand. Maybe in C#, they trust that if you're overlowing, you're doing so intentionally like with hashcode generation for example, and if you yourself don't trust you, the langauge has the checked facility. Additionally, if remembering to nest in a checked is too burdensome, you can change a compiler setting so it is always active, emulating the VB environment.